# CRM 2011 Banners/Branding

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, branding

I was wondering how I might go about applying branding to a CRM 2011 site?

I am looking at adding a customer banner in place of the current Microsoft Dynamics CRM logo placed at the top of each page (in the div above the ribbon at the top)

or alternatively is there a way to replace the section containing the CRM video and following message:

*"Welcome to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Welcome to Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Dashboards help you get started by providing a high-level view of your information."*

With a custom banner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That CRM logo is located on the CRM server @ `..\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\_imgs\CRMMastheadLogo.png`. Its dimensions are 140 x 17. Changing that file changes the logo, and as Daz mentioned, is very unsupported.

Answer (score 8):

Any direct changes you make to the rendered html will be considered unsupported.  This isn't the end of the world but something you'll need to consider when applying the next rollup.

Updating the Getting Started section with your own content is supported.  Here's a link to an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309355.aspx) explaining this.